# Magento crash with httpd memory full... I clear cookies and cache and it´s solved

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a problem with Magento that crashes the site sometimes, and I think that I have found the cause:

1º My normal httpd usage its around 2-3 gb.

2º With my browser, I go to Catalog Price Rules in Magento and then I "Apply and Save" one of the rules.

3º Then, I see that in minutes the httpd its in more than 10gb and increasing...

4º I go to my browser, and I clear cache and cookies of my web.

5º Without touching nothing, the httpd decrease to the normal size of 2-3 gb.

I have a FULL PAGE CACHE and Redis, but I don't know where is the problem and how to solve.
Thanks

Comment: How many products do you have?

Comment: 18200 in total.

Comment: When this is happening? only when `Catalog Price Rules in Magento and then I "Apply and Save" one of the rules.`

Comment: I have "tested" with this and yes, applying and save the cart price rule happens this.